Question 4.31 Heard on the Street - Probability/Game Theory Question
The Question:
Two players A and B play a marble game. Each player has both a red and a blue marble. They present one marble to each other. If both present red, A wins \$3. If both present blue, A wins \$1. If the colors do not match, B wins $2. The winnings come from an external source, not from the other player. Is it better to be A, or B, or does it not matter?
Author's Answer
Assuming that the players have fifty-fifty probabilities of playing Red or Blue, each player has the same expected payoff: $1.
Player B has a variance of payoffs given by
[( 0 − 1 )^2 × 0.5 + ( 2 − 1 )^2 × 0.5] = 1,
whereas player A has a variance of payoffs given by
[( 1 − 1 )^2 × 0.25 + ( 3 − 1 )^2 × 0.25 + ( 0 − 1 )^2 × 0.5] = 1.5
Thus, if you are risk averse, player B’s position is favored (it offers the same
expected return, but less risk).
My Question
It doesn't seem completely game theory optimal to assume A has a 50% chance of choosing red or blue. This is because in either case, A still has a 50% chance of winning because B has equal expected profits with either choice. So, B should still have a 50% chance of choosing between Red or Blue. That said, A should always want to choose Red to guarantee an expected profit of 3/2 = $1.50. Thus, A's variance should likewise be:
[(3 - 1.5)^2 x 0.5 + (0 - 1.5)^2 x 0.5] = 2.25
This obviously complicates the "optimal" player in the problem, since, if we were more profit-seeking and were also more risk adverse, player A might actually be in the better position. But if we were less risk adverse, player B would still be in the better position.
Is there something I'm missing?

As you say, if B plays red/blue with equal probability, it is better for A to play red with probability 1; but then it is better for B to play blue with probability 1; etc; but then it is better for A to play blue with probability 1 etc. So both need to play mixed strategies. If B just plays red/blue with equal probability, then it pays A to play red all the time; in fact, B should play red with probability $\frac{1}{4}$, so there is no temptation for A to defect from their strategy of playing red/blue with equal probability (if A doesn't do this, B can do better by playing the opposite of the more likely one all the time). This assumes they will play multiple games - if it's a one-shot game, it's down to each guessing what their opponent will do, I think.
